# How to format the layout of an NSDate without converting to NSString

Tags: ios

I'm looking to change the way an date object is being put into an nsdictionary
Currently, the date object is being entered in the following format:

```
2014-04-22 17:28:47 +0000
```

However I'd like it to only be entered as

```
22-04-2014
```

I tried using the NSDateFormatter but I've only used it where it's put into a string

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
NSString *theDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

How do I achieve simply changing the layout from `yyyy-mm-dd hh:m:ss ????` to `dd-mm-yyy` but maintain it as a date object?

Comment: the date format stores the date object, theres no need to adjust the date format unless you want to present it visually, so thats why the formatter applies its settings to strings, so that you can represent it the way you like.

Comment: Doesn't this mean there will be issues when trying to find an object? If i'm trying to find 22-04-2014 It will be fairly simple, but if there's no way of formatting it, which means there being a time element of the date object i'd have to reference "22-04-2014 19:09:32" for example..?

Comment: I'm guessing I could also change the way it is firstly input into the dictionary without hindering what I require...

Comment: You would not do something like find `date == searchdate`.. instead you'd search for dates by filtering through their `date` element ignoring the `time` element. Maybe it will be more helpful if you address what it is you're trying to achieve so that I can give a more conclusive response. Also tell us how you're planning to save these date objects

Comment: I guess you could, in one of my projects I was keeping the `date` part of a `datetime stamp` and using that as a `key` inside a dictionary which would then be linked to an array with all the objects related to that date. Then, whenever the user would select a date - I had a cool date slider, where each point would be associated to a specific date - I would use the date linked to it to search through dictionary by doing `[dateBank objectForKey:userSelectedDateString]` which returned the array of objects. it worked nicely. This method would allow you to search with `22-04-2014`, as an example.

Comment: Ok I'll do my best, do say if I'm vague in areas and I'll try to expand - I'm not entirely sure of my exact process yet as I'm new to programming. Essentially, I have a diary entry, and when a UIBarButtonItem is pressed the currently selected date will firstly be checked if it is in the dictionary, and if not it will be put into the dictionary with a unique key Example `/NSString *KeyStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Key%d", dicDates.count+1];` I then want to use this date to be able to apply diary entries too. There can be an unlimited amount of diary entries...continued

Comment: And what happens if more than one entry is made into the diary on the same day? Both of those entries would have the same date element if you are just associating the date itself to each entry.

Comment: ...And to then take these diary entries, concatenate each entry's value and then display their accumulative value in a read only tableview. Ultimately it needs to be an overview (I think with UITableView) that will show a unique date, and then also display accumulated values of each entry within the that date. Please say if  unclear and thank you for reading.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51060/discussion-between-pavan-and-user3547147)

Comment: `And what happens if more than one entry is made into the diary on the same day? Both of those entries would have the same date element if you are just associating the date itself to each entry.` Ideally this should be ok? I'm assuming as you've pointed it out that it's not though.. I haven't quite thought that far into it yet.

Comment: An NSDate ***contains no format information*** (nor does it contain any timezone information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having a discussion with the OP, its been concluded that the following will go a long way in achieving the desired result.

Create a new class that looks something like this

```
//FoodItem . h

NSString *foodItemName;
NSString *foodItemDate;
//You can add more stuff like calorie intake etc

//Have a custom init method
-(id)initNewFoodItemName:(NSString*)name withDate:(NSString*)dateInput;


//THEN IN YOUR 
//FoodItem.m

//Make sure you Synthesise the properties above.
-(id)initNewFoodItemName:(NSString*)name withDate:(NSString*)dateInput{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.foodItemName = name;
        self.foodItemDate = dateInput;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This class is a Data model which you will use to store your data in your database. 
If you dont have one setup but want to have fun with testing out your searching algorithm, you can always create a local temporary manual container that will live for the run time of your program.

Now whether you want to store it in your temporary database or in your local database using apples SQLITE database or using apples Core Data databases; you'll be able to do something awesome like this:

```
NSMutableArray *temporaryDB = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[temporaryDB addObject:[[FoodItem alloc] initNewFoodItemName:@"Banana" withDate:@"2014-04-20"]];
[temporaryDB addObject:[[FoodItem alloc] initNewFoodItemName:@"Egg" withDate:@"2014-03-20"]];
[temporaryDB addObject:[[FoodItem alloc] initNewFoodItemName:@"chocolate" withDate:@"2014-04-18"]];
```

Then when the user selects a specific date because you want to display all the food items that they've eaten on that specific date, you can extract the date from the date picker, convert it into a string using the date formatter, and then search through  the `temporaryDB` array to see if any objects get returned if a date matches, like so:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)searchForAllFoodItemsOnACertainDate:(NSString*)searchDate{
    NSMutableArray *returnedResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for(int i = 0; i < [temporaryDB count]; i++){

        FoodItem *currentFoodItem = [temporary objectAtIndex:i];

        //if a date is found in the temporary DB then store it into the returnedResults array
        if([currentFoodItem.foodItemDate isEqualToString:searchDate]){

            [returnedResults addObject:currentFoodItem];   
        }
    }
    //In the end you will have a all the food items that were eaten on the day or if none was eaten, then an empty array will be returned with a size of 0

    return returnedResults;
}
```

Then somewhere else in the program once the user selects a date, and then clicks the `done` button, you can call the search function like so

```
 NSMutableArray *foodItemsEatenOnChosenDate = [self searchForAllFoodItemsOnACertainDate:dateFromDatePicker];


if([foodItemsEatenOnChosenDate count] > 0){
    //These were the food items eaten on that date the user selected from the date picker
}
else{
    //let the user know that they didnt record any food items on that day
}
```

**Things to remember**

You've got to make sure that the date string you feed into the `foodItemsEatenOnChosenDate` search function is in the same format that you saved the dates in your temporary DB.

Goodluck buddy.